# keyboard stops working when typing my PYPI password in the cmd

Tags: python, pypi

I have logged into the python package index  but when I tried to upload my first python file and pressed 1 to type my username and password , the keyboard at the password section stopped working and when I pressed enter the server response is: "you must login to access this feature" ,but i just cant type the password to login !

Answer (score 0):

type your password and press enter

you won't see any `*`, that doesn't mean your keyboard stopped working (it's invisible)